# Related to RecyclerViews Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am a beginner and need your help to solve this issue.I am facing the replication of views in my `RecyclerView`.After every 5 views the views are repeating automatically.I have gone through several threads here and reddit androiddev as well but none could help.
Basically I am creating a feedback form to fetch opinion of the students and this  came into my way and I am unable to solve it.
I am attaching the screenshot so you can get the gist of the problem.
Please find the code attached below and below that the screenshot comparison.

```
public class GenericViewholder extends CarViewholder {

TextView ques;
TextView tv1, tv2, tv3, tv4, tv5;
LinearLayout counter;
CardView cardview1;
// Firebase mref;
// Button bottomb;
int count = 0;
String database = new String();

public GenericViewholder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    // cardview1 = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view1) ;
    counter = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_counter);
    ques = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.setQuestion);
    tv1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.one);
    tv2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.two);
    tv3 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.three);
    tv4 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.four);
    tv5 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.five);
    // bottomb = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);

    View.OnClickListener clicklistener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.one:
                    if (tv4.getBackground() != null || tv2.getBackground() != null || tv3.getBackground() != null
                            || tv5.getBackground() != null) {
                        tv4.setBackgroundResource(R.color.standardwhite);
                        tv2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.standardwhite);
                        tv3.setBackgroundResource(R.color.standardwhite);
                        tv5.setBackgroundResource(R.color.standardwhite);
                    }


                    tv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fill);
                    count = 1;
                    database = "1";
                    break;
                case R.id.two:
                   if (tv4.getBackground() != null || tv1.getBackground() != null || tv3.getBackground() != null
                            || tv5.getBackground() != null) {
                        tv4.setBackgroundResource(R.color.standardwhite);
                        tv1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.standardwhite);
                        tv3.setBackgroundResource(R.color.standardwhite);
                        tv5.setBackgroundResource(R.color.standardwhite);
                    }

                    tv2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fill);
                    count = 1;
                    database ="2";
                    break;
                case R.id.three:
                   if (tv1.getBackground() != null || tv2.getBackground() != null || tv4.getBackground() != null
                            || tv5.getBackground() != null) {
                        tv1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.standardwhite);
                        tv2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.standardwhite);
                        tv4.setBackgroundResource(R.color.standardwhite);
                        tv5.setBackgroundResource(R.color.standardwhite);
                    }

                    tv3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fill);
                    count= 1;
                    database = "3";
                    break;
                case R.id.four:
                   if (tv1.getBackground() != null || tv2.getBackground() != null || tv3.getBackground() != null
                            || tv5.getBackground() != null) {
                        tv1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.standardwhite);
                        tv2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.standardwhite);
                        tv3.setBackgroundResource(R.color.standardwhite);
                        tv5.setBackgroundResource(R.color.standardwhite);
                    }

                    tv4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fill);
                    count =1;
                    database = "4";

                    break;
                case R.id.five:
                    if (tv4.getBackground() != null || tv2.getBackground() != null || tv3.getBackground() != null
                            || tv1.getBackground() != null) {
                        tv1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.standardwhite);
                        tv2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.standardwhite);
                        tv3.setBackgroundResource(R.color.standardwhite);
                        tv4.setBackgroundResource(R.color.standardwhite);
                    }

                    tv5.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fill);
                    count = 1;
                    database ="5" ;
                    // b5.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    break;
                default:
                    count = 0;
                    database ="0" ;

            }
            //Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Rating set : " + value.getRating(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    };

    if(tv1.getBackground() != null ||tv2.getBackground() != null ||tv3.getBackground() != null ||tv4.getBackground() != null ||tv5.getBackground() != null )
    {
        count = 1;
    }
    else
        count = 0;

    tv1.setOnClickListener(clicklistener);
    tv2.setOnClickListener(clicklistener);
    tv3.setOnClickListener(clicklistener);
    tv4.setOnClickListener(clicklistener);
    tv5.setOnClickListener(clicklistener);


}
```

}

```
 public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CarViewholder> {
/*
Important thing to notice here is that the multiple viewholders are needed to be checked and aligned
with respect to the position and viewtype of the layout
Viewtype: returns default value 0 for similar layout so we overrided it with two values
one for the cardview and one for the Master submit section
 Pl note :::: Always create different child classes and extend it to the master class to get better result and
 better judge of the execution taking place.
 OncreateViewholder creates and inflates the view so here we need to distinctly create different objects of
 child classes to get different results

 */

List<String> dbObjList = new ArrayList<>();
public static int CARD_VAL = 1;
public static int BUTTON_VAL = 2;
int countercount = 0;
String[] ques = {"How would you grade the Teachers",
        "How Did You Find The Study Material",
        "How Was The Coaching Infrastructure",
        "How Innovative Were The Teachers",
        "Ease Of Travel To The Class",
        "Previous Years' Results",
        "Extra-Curricular Activities",
        "Counselling During Admission",
        "Clear Your Doubts Sessions",
        "How Were The Tests Conducted",
        "How Were The Seminars",
        "How Were The Powerpoint Presentations",
        "Quality of tests in regular time intervals",
        "Syllabus coverage in tests",
        "Test results/feedback on time",
        "Doubt clearance after tests",
        "Remedial classes after tests"};
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
// View iview;

public CardAdapter(Context context) {

    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public CarViewholder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    CarViewholder viewholder ;
    View iview;
    if (viewType == CARD_VAL) {
            iview = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false);
            viewholder = new GenericViewholder(iview);
            iview.setTag(viewholder);
         return viewholder;
    } else {
        iview = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.button, parent, false);
        viewholder = new ButtonViewHolder(iview);
        return viewholder;

    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CarViewholder holder, int position) {
    if (getItemViewType(position) == BUTTON_VAL || position == getItemCount() + 1) {
        Log.i("DEBUG", "hun" + getItemViewType(position));

        ButtonViewHolder buttonViewHolder = (ButtonViewHolder) holder;
        Log.i("DEBUG", "" + getItemViewType(position));

        Log.i("DEBUG", "hun" + getItemViewType(position));

        buttonViewHolder.bottombutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                int countt = 0;
                Log.i("Checking the database", dbObjList.toString());
                for (int i = 0; i< dbObjList.size();i++)
                {
                    if(dbObjList.get(i).equals("") || dbObjList.get(i).equals("0"))
                        countt++;
                }
                Log.i("Checking the database", countt + "");
                if (countt == 0) {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext())
                            .setTitle("Title")
                            .setMessage("Do you really want to submit?")
                            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Submitted your response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null).show()
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Still left to submit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    if (getItemViewType(position) == CARD_VAL && position <= getItemCount()) {
        Log.i("DEBUG", "" + getItemViewType(position));
        GenericViewholder genericViewholder = (GenericViewholder) holder;
        dbObjList.add(position,genericViewholder.database);
        if(genericViewholder != null)
        if(genericViewholder.count == 1){
            countercount++;
            Log.i("THE value of count :",countercount+"");
        }
        genericViewholder.ques.setText(ques[position]);
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return ques.length + 1;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    //check for the termination point
    //for the last point insert button
    return (position < ques.length) ? CARD_VAL : BUTTON_VAL;


}
```

}

[Find the screenshots here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roDOn.png)

Answer (score 0):

try declaring your buttonview holder outside onBindViewHolder
because as onBindViewHolder runs on every time a view binds 
. so this might be causing your views to repeat

Comment: Hi Ravi,I greatly appreciate your help but the repetition of views was happening even before the buttonview holder was used by me.Even when i removed the buttonviewholder,I am facing the same changes.I believe its because somehow I am unable to reset the initially created views because after recycling those views are again used as it is hence the repetition but I dont know how to remove or reset them.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change extends in `classCardAdapter` class

```
public classCardAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<classCardAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder>
```

and change the method:

```
@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
//all stuff

}
```

Create a class of `RecyclerViewHolder`  that will hold all the view data